# escaping angularjs markup with non ascii character

Tags: angularjs, markup

can anyone see any technical issues with using Ⓐ to wrap my angularjs markup?

i.e.

```
app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('Ⓐ').endSymbol('Ⓐ');
}]);
```

I've tested on firefox and chome on ubuntu, they both work fine.

I'm looking for a technical reason why I shouldn't use it rather than a style or *'I don't know how to type Ⓐ'* type reason.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the lack of support from monospaced fonts and syntax highlighting? It restricts both JS file and the document to UTF-8. Ⓐ is a 3-byte character, there may be cheaper delimiters.

There are no nested expressions in Angular, so single character for both `startSymbol` and `endSymbol` should cause no issues.